# Extracting .gz after download through command line ftp

Tags: ftp, unzip, gzip

I'm trying to download a large number of files with the extension ".seq.gz" (1907 to be exact), so I'm using 'mget' on my windows command line ftp shell. When trying to unzip the files using WinZip I keep getting this error:

> Extracting to "C:\Users\AljanahiA\AppData\Local\Temp\wz1a02\"
>
> Use Path: yes   Overlay Files: yes
>
> Extracting gbvrt7.seq
>
> Severe Error:  CRC of extracted file does not match stored value.

Of course the same thing happens when I use 'get' and download a single file. BUT, when I manually download the files from the ftp webpage, it unzips perfectly fine. 
Thoughts?

Comment: Is your FTP session defaulting to 'ASCII' mode (which translates line endings, and can corrupt binary files)?

Comment: @JimLewis yes it is, how do I change that?

Comment: FTP has a BINARY command (and also an ASCII command) to disable/enable line ending translation.  It sounds like using the BINARY command before downloading the files should fix your problem.

Comment: @JimLewis it did! thanks a million!